# My MacBook Pro keeps restarting/quitting apps. What is the reason?

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, bluetooth, kernel-panic

Since I bought my Macbook Pro 13-inch in July 2020, I have experienced with strange issues. For example, Safari sometimes quits unexpectedly, the Finder freezes, the Bluetooth doesn't work properly with the AirPods Pro (for example, sometimes the audio is sent to the right headphone only).

Today my Macbook Pro restarted during the night (while it was closed maybe?)
This is the report that I sent to Apple. Can anyone tell me what is the problem?
Thanks

```
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff8000bfe647): "IOBluetoothHostControllerUARTTransport::setPowerState(0xffffff936c993400 : 0xffffff8002a2ca16, 1 -> 0) timed out after 20505 ms"@/AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-7195.50.7/iokit/Kernel/IOServicePM.cpp:5382
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffffb0c9ad3ac0 : 0xffffff80004bc66d 
0xffffffb0c9ad3b10 : 0xffffff80005ff073 
0xffffffb0c9ad3b50 : 0xffffff80005ef6aa 
0xffffffb0c9ad3ba0 : 0xffffff8000461a2f 
0xffffffb0c9ad3bc0 : 0xffffff80004bbf0d 
0xffffffb0c9ad3ce0 : 0xffffff80004bc1f8 
0xffffffb0c9ad3d50 : 0xffffff8000cbee1a 
0xffffffb0c9ad3dc0 : 0xffffff8000bfe647 
0xffffffb0c9ad3e10 : 0xffffff8000bfdf69 
0xffffffb0c9ad3e20 : 0xffffff8000c16a1e 
0xffffffb0c9ad3e60 : 0xffffff8000bfcce8 
0xffffffb0c9ad3e80 : 0xffffff8000501345 
0xffffffb0c9ad3ef0 : 0xffffff8000502254 
0xffffffb0c9ad3fa0 : 0xffffff800046113e 

Process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task
Boot args: chunklist-security-epoch=0 -chunklist-no-rev2-dev

Mac OS version:
20B29

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 20.1.0: Sat Oct 31 00:07:11 PDT 2020; root:xnu-7195.50.7~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 84C6DC45-6B02-335F-9439-5D2A9BC385A4
KernelCache slide: 0x0000000000200000
KernelCache base:  0xffffff8000400000
Kernel slide:      0x0000000000210000
Kernel text base:  0xffffff8000410000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8000300000
System model name: MacBookPro16,2 (Mac-5F9802EFE386AA28)
System shutdown begun: NO
Hibernation exit count: 0

System uptime in nanoseconds: 592256998272238
Last Sleep:           absolute           base_tsc          base_nano
  Uptime  : 0x00021aa793ffae9d
  Sleep   : 0x00021aa072200bd8 0x00048e877e616ef5 0x00021a9a40d2cf6a
  Wake    : 0x00021aa076361988 0x00049b9eb2252611 0x00021aa074506e6e
last started kext at 591484675276159: >usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice   1.2 (addr 0xffffff8003398000, size 40960)
last stopped kext at 589818245659048: >usb.!UUserHCI    1 (addr 0xffffff7f9ffef000, size 98304)
loaded kexts:
>usb.!UUserHCI  1
>AGPM   119
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    4000.27
>!AHIDALSService    1
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
@fileutil   20.036.15
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 6.1.27
>!A!IICLGraphics    16.0.0
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   6.1.27
>!ABridgeAudio!C    100.2
>pmtelemetry    1
>LuaHardwareAccess  1.0.16
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
|IO!BSerialManager  8.0.1f5
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>!AHV   1
>!A!IICLLPGraphicsFramebuffer   16.0.0
>BridgeAudioCommunication   100.2
>!ABacklight    180.3
>!AAVEBridge    6.1
>!AGFXHDA   100.1.431
>!AMCCSControl  1.14
>!A!IPCHPMC 2.0.1
>!ADiskImages2  1
>!AThunderboltIP    4.0.3
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
@filesystems.apfs   1677.50.1
>BCMWLANFirmware4378.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4377.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4364.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4355.Hashstore  1
@filesystems.tmpfs  1
@filesystems.hfs.kext   556.41.1
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
>!ABCMWLANBusInterfacePCIeMac   1
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
@nke.applicationfirewall    310
|IOKitRegistryCompatibility 1
|EndpointSecurity   1
>usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
>!UAudio    401.4
>!AHS!BDriver   4000.27
>IO!BHIDDriver  8.0.1f5
>!AHIDKeyboard  222
>!AActuatorDriver   4400.28
>!AMultitouchDriver 4400.28
>!AInputDeviceSupport   4400.35
@kext.triggers  1.0
>!AGraphicsControl  6.1.27
|IOAVB!F    900.12
|IOAccelerator!F2   439.35.4
|IO!BHost!CUARTTransport    8.0.1f5
|IO!BHost!CTransport    8.0.1f5
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
>!A!ILpssUARTv1 3.0.60
>!A!ILpssUARTCommon 3.0.60
>!AOnboardSerial    1.0
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
|IONDRVSupport  585
|IOAudio!F  300.6.1
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
@!AGPUWrangler  6.1.27
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    6.1.27
|IOGraphics!F   585
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    900.11
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
>usb.cdc.ncm    5.0.0
>usb.cdc    5.0.0
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
>usb.!UHub  1.2
>usb.!UVHCIBCE  1.2
>usb.!UVHCICommonBCE    1.0
>usb.!UVHCI 1.2
>usb.!UVHCICommon   1.0
>!AEffaceableNOR    1.0
|IOBufferCopy!C 1.1.0
|IOBufferCopyEngine!F   1
|IONVMe!F   2.1.0
>!ABSDKextStarter   3
|IOSurface  289.3
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    4.1.1
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   8.1.4
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   8.1.4
>!AHPM  3.4.4
>!A!ILpssI2C!C  3.0.60
>!A!ILpssI2C    3.0.60
>!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
>!ABCMWLANCoreMac   1.0.0
|IOSerial!F 11
|IO80211!FV2    1200.12.2b1
|IOSkywalk!F    1
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>IOImageLoader  1.0.0
>corecapture    1.0.4
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>!AThunderboltNHI   7.2.8
|IOThunderbolt!F    9.3.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
>!ASMCRTC   1.0
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$!AImage4   3.0.0
|IOTimeSync!F   900.11
|IONetworking!F 3.4
>DiskImages 493.0.0
|IO!B!F 8.0.1f5
|IOReport!F 47
|IO!BPacketLogger   8.0.1f5
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>!ASSE  1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  511.40.9
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  184.40.6
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  436.40.6
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  436.40.6
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
>watchdog   1
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.corecrypto 1.0
@kec.Libm   1
```

Comment: What is the macOS version on it? Have you installed all the latest OS updates? Also, open `Console` and check if it shows any errors and faults. If yes, post it here. If you bought it in July 2020, it should still be under warranty - contact Apple support and let them have a look at it just in case its some hardware issue. If the hardware fails after warranty, it's going to be an expensive repair.

Comment: Exactly the same problem!